# Viewing Django and webpack built site on LAN

Tags: python, django, webpack, lan, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to view my locally served site on other devices such as my phone or another laptop. On my current laptop the site works fine, I see everything (frontend) and I get 200s when I visit the site.

However, when I try to access the site with my iphone and second laptop, I do not see any frontend but I do get 200s when I try to access the site. The terminal on my working machine also tells me that there are requests coming in.

I use `Django` as a backend and I bundle/build my Javascript and CSS with `webpack` and serve it with `webpack-dev-server`.

When I run webpack I see this message:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/
webpack result is served from http://localhost:3000/public/bundle/
content is served from ./public
```

When I load my webpage on my working machine, the developer tools shows this:

[image]

and everything is working.

I run django with this command.

`$ ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

My `ifconfig` gives me:

`inet 192.168.1.102`

With my second laptop, I visit `192.168.1.102:8000` and I see nothing on my page. I get a `200` on my machine with the site working meaning the requests has gone through. On my second laptop I see this in the developer tools:

[image]

Notice it doesnt have `/public/` in the `src` and `href`

On my second machine if I visit `192.168.1.102:3000` I see an Interface and I am able to click around to `192.168.1.102:3000/bundle/main.js` and see my webpack built javascript.

On my second machine, I tried to change the src and href in my developer tools to `192.168.1.102:3000/bundle/main.js`. However nothing would change and I still see a blank screen

Here is a `gist` of my webpack config:

https://gist.github.com/liondancer/7685b53dffa50d7d102d

Answer (score 4):

I believe your page is empty because the whole "app" is generated by javascript (it seems so in your two screenshots at least, assuming that the content of `<div id="app"></div>` is not generated by a django view) but the javascript file is not accessible to clients that are different from your development machine.

It's hard to guess why this is happening without your `settings.py`, `urls.py` and the code/template of the `view` generating your home page but we have some candidates that may be generating this issues: CORS, localhost "poisoning" and eventually STATIC_URL misconfiguration.

1. CORS: A request is considered cross-domain if any of the scheme,
   hostname, or **port** do not match. You are requesting file both from `localhost:8000` (or `192.168.1.102:8000`) and from `localhost:3000`. So CORS issues will rise if you request files from an external device/laptop;
2. `localhost` is the same machine
   as 192.168.1.102 on your "working computer" but it isn't on your second
   laptop or any other device in your network;
3. Do you generate the URLs for css and js files using `{% url %}` or `{% static %}` tags? It seems no, but still they look dynamically generated (i.e. the missing "public/" part of their URL). I'm not aware of a way to get different paths using vanilla Django and the same settings, so you should provide the source code of your view, at least, to get a precise answer.

**Solutions** (or, at least, hints :-) ):

1. Serve the bundle from the same port (add them to your [STATIC path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/))
2. Replace every `localhost` reference in your html URLs (it may require to change your `sites` - see [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/))
3. Use standard template tags/filters and avoid hard-coded URLs in templates and code.

or install https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader/ (`pip install django-webpack-loader`) and follow their README or http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/ guide

Comment: Here is the source to my project: https://github.com/liondancer/django-cherngloong. I will try out your suggestions and update you